# Cookies javascript em webview smartphones!

Tags: javascript, android, html5, windows-phone, iso-8859-1

Gostaria de saber se alguém sabe utilizar ou se sabe informar se pega Cookies diretamente do webview do aparelho smartphones..

Sei que são funções de um navegador, mas estou fazendo um APP que ele precisa salvar temporariamente ou permanente, ate que seja trocado, o login do usuário, e o app é inteiramente em HTML, ou seja não é bem uma aplicação do tipo JAVA, mas HTML5, CSS3 e JAVASCRIPT.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E para que o usuário não tenha que ficar logando toda vez que abrir o app gostaria de salvar esses dados do login de alguma forma no aparelho, seja de forma cookies, ou criando um arquivo tipo txt com as informações...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução mais fiável é o [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). O `localStorage` é um objeto onde podes gravar strings nas chaves desse objeto e que não tem tempo limite.

Por exemplo:

```
localStorage.appUser = 'Pedro';
```

e mais tarde podes usar `localStorage.appUser` para saber qual o valor que está gravado.

No javaScript não podes gravar ficheiros. Podes sempre enviar para o servidor mas se queres guardar no computador/browser onde o utilizador está então `localStorage` é o que aconselho usares.

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/y6Lpu8m1/

Comment: Mas digamos que o usuário feche o aplicativo ou reinicie o celular aplicativo, essa função manterá a valor?

Comment: @PedroQuezado testa o jsFiddle que fiz. Tem um campo `primeiroLogin` e outro `ultimoLogin`. Repara como o primeiro fica sempre o mesmo e o segundo vai sendo atualizado.

Comment: sabe informar o porque que esse comando não esta funcionando?? `$(document).ready(function(){
    if(localStorage.userlogin !== "undefined") {
        alert(localStorage.userlogin);
    };
});`

Comment: o código em geral... http://jsfiddle.net/pedroquezado/qafk7j67/ deveria dar um **alert()** retornando o **localStorage.userlogin** somente se tivesse sido preenchido, no caso diferente de undefined, mas mesmo assim ele da um alert.. FAILL! ;(

Comment: @PedroQuezado usa `typeof` assim: http://jsfiddle.net/y6Lpu8m1/1/

Comment: quando o usuário sair? Posso limpar o **localStorage** com `localStorage.clear();`?